# JavaScriptのbeforeunloadイベント内でリロードとクローズを判別する方法について

Tags: javascript

Webサイトのタブが閉じられる際に確認メッセージを表示したいのですが、
JavaScriptのbeforeunloadイベント内でページのリロードによって発生したイベントなのか、
ページが閉じられたことによるイベントなのかを判断する方法はありますでしょうか。
いまのところ通常の画面遷移に関してはイベントが発生しないように制御できているのですが、
リロードとクローズの区別がつかないためリロード時にも確認メッセージが表示されてしまうような状態です。
どうにかしてタブを閉じるときだけメッセージが表示されるようにしたいのですが。。。

Comment: 参考: 英語版での関連質問 - [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3888902)